# Compiling C++/CLI .exe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, compilation, c++-cli

I wrote a C++/CLR Windows Form program and it works fine on the compiler computer but not on any others. The target computers have .Net4 and the C++ redistribution pack. I really don't understand how the settings need to be set and the info on the web concerning this stuff is very confusing for a beginner. How do I need to have my compiler set so that I can get this program to run? If I need to link .dll's how do I go about doing that. Here are the key settings as I know:
The Runtime Library is set to /MDd; MFC:Standard Windows Libaries; ATL:Static Link to ATL; CLR:/clr:pure.

Edit: If I install VS on taget computers I can open the .exe without a problem, not even opening VS or loading any source files. It seems it's still dependent on VS somehow, any idea's on this and how to over come it?

Answer (score 1):

/MDd specifies a dynamic **debug** CRT, this won't be installed by the standard CRT redistributable MSI

Try putting a release build on the target machine instead.

Comment: I tried that but no luck. The program doesn't throw any error's but nothing happens when I try to launch it.

Comment: Try running http://www.dependencywalker.com/ on the exe on the target system to see what it reports.

Comment: I got the following errors: Modules with different CPU types were found. At least one delay-load dependency module was not found. At least one module has unresolved import due to a missing export function in delay-load dependent module. Not sure what any of that means.

Comment: I also received the same error's on my compiler computer, however the program launch's fine despite this.

Comment: I'd install WinDbg on the target machine run the exe under it to see if any exceptions or errors are reported.  Sometimes an exception thrown earlier enough can cause a problem to appear to disappear quietly.

Comment: You need the 32-bit version of Dependency Walker to troubleshoot 32-bit software.